# Make element fill the width of its container AND not have margins push it out of that container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to have an element fill the width of it's container dynamically and have margins but not overflow that container?

```css
body {
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:12px;
}

#BorderContainer2085  {
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:37px;
 width:340px;
 height:160px;
 display:inline-block;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#696969;
 border-style:solid;
 border-radius:0px;
}

#Button1199  {
 position:absolute;
 top:19px;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer2085">
 <input id="Button1199" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

Here is what I'm getting with my code:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `width:calc(100% - 40px);` for button element - does it give expected effect?

Example:

```css
body {
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:12px;
}

#BorderContainer2085  {
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:37px;
 width:240px;
 height:160px;
 display:inline-block;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#696969;
 border-style:solid;
 border-radius:0px;
}

#Button1199  {
 position:absolute;
 top:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
 width:calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer2085">
 <input id="Button1199" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

Comment: better answer for the "dynamic width" part of the OPs question. +1

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

#BorderContainer2085 {
  border-color: #696969;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 160px;
  left: 37px;

  /* Add this */
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  width: 340px;
}

#Button1199 {
  /* You have to change absolute with relative
  position:absolute;*/
  position: relative;
  
  top: 19px;
  
  /* Remove this
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:20px;
  */
  
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer2085">
 <input id="Button1199" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you made to the code outside of the code snippet, so readers will know what you've changed.